# Java TreeSet sorting objects by value

Tags: java, swing, sorting, treeset

I posted about this application yesterday, but now I'm having a different problem. I'm currently working on this application for tracking track (tracking track?) day runs and displaying a leaderboard. This is for a class so I'm not looking for code necessarily, just some thoughts on how to go about it. Anyway, the application currently will take input information (from the bottom textfields), create a TreeSet of RaceEntrant objects (class shown below), and create a queue on the right which is emptied as the participants go through their runs. The problem is, I need the TreeSet to be sorted in the (grey) leaderboard area from smallest to largest runTime and update while the times are entered at the top. I'm kind of unsure how to have it sort the objects specifically by the runTime. Any help is appreciated.

RaceEntrant Class

```
class RaceEntrant
{
  private String name,
                 car;
  private double runTime;

  public RaceEntrant(String name, String car)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = car;
  }    

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String getCar()
  {
    return car;
  }   

  public double getTime()
  {
    return runTime;  
  }

  public void setTime(double time)
  {
      this.runTime = time;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() 
  {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
      sb.append(getName());
      sb.append("     ");
      sb.append(getCar());
      sb.append("\n" );
      sb.append("Best time: " + getTime() + "\n");
      return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

This is an example of the current operation - the RaceEntrant(s) are displayed in order of their runs, not sorted by anything. I apologize for the lengthy post. 
[image: app example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `TreeSet` is not the right data structure. A `TreeSet` is above all a `Set` -- which keys are considered unique based on comparison.

I think you can have identical run times?

Maybe just use an `ArrayList` and sort it using `Collections.sort()` with a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Ah, I somehow hadn't considered the possibility of identical run times. Thanks, I'll see how an ArrayList goes.

Answer (score 1):

Your class, RaceEntrant, should implements Comparable, and you can control order in the implemented method compareTo.

Your class could look like this:

```
class RaceEntrant implements Comparable<RaceEntrant>
{
  private final String name,
                 car;
  private double runTime;

  public RaceEntrant(final String name, final String car)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = car;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String getCar()
  {
    return car;
  }

  public double getTime()
  {
    return runTime;
  }

  public void setTime(final double time)
  {
      this.runTime = time;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
      final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
      sb.append(getName());
      sb.append("     ");
      sb.append(getCar());
      sb.append("\n" );
      sb.append("Best time: " + getTime() + "\n");
      return sb.toString();
  }

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if(this == obj) return true;
    if (obj instanceof RaceEntrant){
    return (((RaceEntrant) obj).getTime() == runTime) && ((RaceEntrant) obj).getName().equals(name) && ((RaceEntrant) obj).getCar().equals(car);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new Double(runTime).intValue();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(final RaceEntrant o) {
    return new Double(o.runTime).compareTo(this.runTime)*-1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your RaceEntrant class:

```
class RaceEntrant implements Comparable<RaceEntrant>{
  //..

  public int compareTo(RaceEntrant re){
    return getTime().compareTo(re.getTime());
  }

  @Override   //optional for Sets
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    If(o != null && o instanceOf RaceEntrant){
      RaceEntrant entrant = (RaceEntrant)o;
      return getName().equals(entrant.getName() &&
             getCar().equals(entrant.getCar()) &&
             getTime() == entrant.getTime();
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can sort your List (probably ArrayList) by runTime.
You could also use a TreeSet (this should be sorted automatically) and define a equals method on runTime + name + car if that's a possible approach.